# How to include view related javascript (*.js) files in the views folder in nodejs?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, model-view-controller

I have been writing all the Javascript code of my html template file within the html file itself but when the logic grows and gets complicated it makes sense to seperately link the javascript script file .

But I am running the node.js express server and the javascript file is not in the `public` path .

How to whitelist this .js file and what efficient ways are there to included view realted `.js` files while running a **`nodejs`** server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use the `express.static()` http://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html for more reference